# inserted value into model, with SelectWithPop, but page is not updated unless I restart the server

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

So, I've a form with SelectWithPop. So the user can select a variable or he can add one more.
A new page is open for the user to enter data.

My problem is that I'm able to insert a new variable into the model but when I return to the page to select a value, the new value is not shown until I restart the server.
Is this behavior normal or I've done something wrong?
If it is, is there any way to overcome this issue?

Here are my views:

```
def add(request, field):
    return handlePopAdd(request, HospitalForm, 'hospital_name')

def handlePopAdd(request, addForm, field):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = addForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                newObject = form.save()
            except forms.ValidationError, error:
                newObject = None
            if newObject:
               return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('form', args=['clinical']))
    else:
        form = addForm()
    return render_to_response("popadd.html", { 'form': form })
```

forms:

```
class CheckPatForm(forms.Form):
    pat = forms.IntegerField(label="Paciente")

    _names = list(Hospital.objects.values_list('hospital_id', 'hospital_name'))
    _names.append(('',''))

    hosp = forms.ChoiceField(_names, widget=SelectWithPop(), label="Hospital", required=False)
    proc = forms.IntegerField(label="Processo", required=False)

class HospitalForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hospital
```

templates add:

```
<a
href="/SIAM-TB/insert/form/add/{{ field }}"
class="add-another"
id="add_id_{{ field }}">
    <img src="http://rome/SIAM-TB/admin_media/img/admin/icon_addlink.gif" 
         width="10" height="10" alt="Add Another"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the code that gets the hospital queryset into the forms init. e.g.

```
....

hosp = forms.ChoiceField(widget=SelectWithPop(), label="Hospital", required=False)

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CheckPatForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    names = list(Hospital.objects.values_list('hospital_id', 'hospital_name'))
    names.append(('',''))
    self.fields['hosp'].choices = names
```